# What would be the dissipative function for a nonlinear nonconservative force in lagrangian?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, drag, dissipation

For a nonconservative force, What would be the dissipative function for a force $f=-bvⁿ$ in Lagrangian (Where $v$ is the velocity). [For a non-conservative force $f=-bv$, The dissipative function is $D=-\frac{1}{2}bv^2$ .]
Since $f=\frac{\partial D}{\partial{ \dot{x}}}$ so the dissipative function should be $D=-b\dfrac{v^{n+1}}{n+1}$, Isn't it?

Comment: Welcome to SE. "Do my work for me" questions aren't allowed. Show what you tried to do and people will discuss it or suggest modifications. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me! I'm new here and don't know the system very well! As per what you said, I have attached a picture!

Comment: No problem. About your edit, however: you should also avoid screenshots, especially low-quality like the one you added. Use the Mathjax tool provided here to typeset equations (it's LaTeX syntax, mostly).

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you!

Comment: [cross-posted](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/find-dissipative-function-for-the-non-linear-force-f-bv-n.1016689/)